# In python, how to locate the position of the empty rows in the middle of the file and skip some rows at the beginning dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The data in an excel file looks like this

```
A   B   C       
1   1   1       
1   1   1       

D   E   F   G   H
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
```

The file is separated into two parts by one empty row in the middle of the file. They have different column names and different number of columns. I only need the second part of the file. I want to read this file as a pandas dataframe. The number of rows in the first part is not fixed, different files will have different number of rows. So if I use skiprows=4 will not work.

I actually already have a solution for that. But I want to know whether there is a better solution.

```py
import pandas as pd


path = r'C:\Users\'
file = 'test-file.xlsx'

# Read the whole file without skipping
df_temp = pd.read_excel(path + '/' + file)
```

The data looks like this in pandas. Empty row will have null values in all the columns.

```
     A    B    C Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0    1    1    1        NaN        NaN
1    1    1    1        NaN        NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN
3    D    E    F          G          H
4    1    1    1          1          1
5    1    1    1          1          1
```

I try to find all empty rows and return the index of the first empty row

```py
first_empty_row = df_temp[df_temp.isnull().all(axis=1)].index[0]

del df_temp
```

Read the file again but skip number of rows by using the number provided above

```py
df= pd.read_excel(path + '/' + file, skiprows=first_empty_row+2)
print(df)
```

The drawback of this solution is I need to read the file twice. If the file has a lot of rows in the first part, it might take a long time to read these useless rows. I can also possibly use readline loop rows until it reach an empty row, but that will be inefficient.

Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks

Comment: Is there ever another row with all NaN's or will that always be the only one?

Answer (score 1):

Find the position if the first empty row:

```
pos = df_temp[df_temp.isnull().all(axis=1)].index[0]
```

Then select everything after that position:

```
df = df_temp.iloc[pos+1:]
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df.columns.name = ''       
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work. The result is A             D
B             E
C             F
Unnamed: 3    G
Unnamed: 4    H            Because the columns name for the second block is missing. the return value is strange

Answer (score 0):

Your first line looks across the entire row for all null. Would it be possible to just look for the first null in the first column?

```
first_empty_row = df_temp[df_temp.isnull().all(axis=1)].index[0]
```

How does this compare in performance?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'A' : [1,1, np.NaN, 'D', 1,1],
         'B' : [1,1, np.NaN, 'E', 1,1],
         'C' : [1,1, np.NaN, 'F', 1,1],
         'Unnamed: 3' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN, 'G', 1,1],
         'Unnamed: 4' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN, 'H', 1,1]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

print(df1)

     A    B    C Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4
0    1    1    1        NaN        NaN
1    1    1    1        NaN        NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN        NaN        NaN
3    D    E    F          G          H
4    1    1    1          1          1
5    1    1    1          1          1

# create empty list to append the rows that need to be deleted
list1 = []

# loop through the first column of the dataframe and append the index to a list until the row is null
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if (pd.isnull(row[0])):
        list1.append(index)
        break
    else:
        list1.append(index)

# drop the rows based on list created from for loop
df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[list1])

# reset index so you can replace the old columns names 
# with the secondary column names easier
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop = True)

# create empty list to append the new column names to
temp = []

# loop through dataframe and append the new column names
for label in df1.columns:
    temp.append(df1[label][0])

# replace column names with the desired names
df1.columns = temp

# drop the old column names which are always going to be at row 0
df1 = df1.drop(df1.index[0])

# reset index so it doesn't start at 1
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop = True)

print(df1)

   D  E  F  G  H
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  1  1
```